# cannot connect to database access denied localhost

Tags: mysql, hibernate, intellij-idea

I've tried all the tips that I found on the internet and cannot resolve this error.
Everything was good with my mysql until I put a folder project from git in intellij in which I had a connection to mysql. In the hibernate file I put the user and the password and when I try to open mysql, it says to enter my password but whatever I put it gives the error:

```
Error Message Cannot Connect to Database Server

Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306.Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password: yes)

Please: 1. Check that mysql is running on server localhost.

Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)

Check the root has rights to connect to localhost from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines)

Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for localhost connecting from the host address you're connecting from
```

I have tried to change in the manage connection Standard TCP/IP with Local Socket/Pipe and another tips that I found on the net but without success.
If anyone has some advice please answer.

Comment: Some how you change the password in whatever is making the connection. Either use phpMyAdmin to set the root password to what you are using or fix the password you are using to connect

Comment: Are you able to connect to mysql from the console with root as the username?

Comment: No, I wasn't. So I have reinstalled mysql and now works.